# I am trying to run selenium code and get this error. I already downloaded the latest chromedriver version. Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Tags: java

I am trying to run selenium code and get this error. I already downloaded the latest chromedriver version. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created.

```
package basics.selenuim;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class LunchBrowsers {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\chromedriver.exe");

       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
       driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

       driver.get("https://www.cnn.com/");

       String siteTitle = driver.getTitle();
       System.out.println(siteTitle);

       Thread.sleep(5000);
       driver.close();

   } 
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're not going to any website? After you set the settings (everything with the `driver.manage()`), add a line `driver.get(url)`

Comment: @sabraship, sorry for confusion, there was some comments in my code so i delete the get url as well with it now I added in the code. In my the code is correct and i just run it and got this error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created

Comment: that code worked for me. I am using Chromedriver version 83.0.4103.39

Comment: I fixed it thank you the problem was with my chromedriver